# How can I completely remove deleted photos/videos?

Tags: internal-storage, delete

I have an LG G5.  Last week I recorded a 20 minute video using my camera phone.  The file size was ~3 Gb. I don't use the SD card, so the video saved in the gallery.   I saved the video to Google drive and deleted it from my gallery.  Even after restarting my phone, and doing a soft reset by removing the battery, the 3Gb of storage has not been recovered.  My phone still thinks the video is there in internal storage, although its no longer visible in the gallery. 
 I had a similar  problem once before, and was able to 'explore' the internal storage through settings --> storage, and I found a hidden trash folder that I could empty to finally free up the space.  That was only 3 months ago.  Now, when I try the same trick and explore the internal storage, I can neither find nor remember where that hidden trash bin was before.  Any thoughts???  Thank you!!!

Comment: Ok, so, I feel a little silly, but I just looked again and found that trash bin.  Its in Android -> data -> com.android.gallery3d -> files -> .trashcan.

Comment: ..so now my question is - is there a better way than having to delete things twice??